# Angular show one drop-down list based on upper drop-down list value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two drop-down lists. The second drop-down list is hidden until the first drop-down list has any value other than "None" selected. Is there an easy way to do this using angular directives only? I don't want to have to use a $scope function again. Seems rudimentary enough to do directly. Please help.

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
        Select month:
        </div>
        <select>
        <option selected>None</option>
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option>March</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>June</option>
        <option>July</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>September</option>
        <option>October</option>
        <option>November</option>
        <option>December</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
        Select month:
        </div>
        <select>
        <option selected>1st</option>
        <option>2nd</option>
        <option>3rd</option>
        <option>4th</option>
        <option>5th</option>
        <option>6th</option>
        <option>7th</option>
        <option>8th</option>
        <option>9th</option>
        <option>10th</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    </div>
```

Comment: you could make it hidden by using `ng-show`/`ng-if`, or you could just disabled that filed using `ng-disabled="expression"`

Comment: Could you please show me how I would do that in this case in my code?

Comment: Was the answer helpful? Do you need more information?

Comment: It's ok I'll figure it out on my own. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to bind the selects to $scope variables anyhow if you want to process the selection further so the first list could be:

```
    <select ng-model="select1">
      ....
    </select>
```

and the second:

```
    <select ng-model="select2" ng-if="select1 != null">  
      ....
    </select>
```

Comment: Is there no way I can reference the first drop-downlist and say: If drop-down list 1's value is not "None", ng-show drop-down list 2?

Comment: Yes there is, by a model variable. You cannot reference one HTML structure from another (with some exception like labels).

Comment: I honestly don't know how I would go about doing that. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `ng-if="select1"` is enough

Comment: What are you missing in my answer? To make it clear: if you want to use Angular, you have to use $scope as the unifying model. If you don't feel like having $scope variables and functions, then Angular is not for you. @PankajParkar: thanks!